# How to get data from dead SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

My OS SSD died and I wonder if there is any way to get some data from it.

The disk light shines bright so I think power is OK. 
But It is not detected in BIOS neither in Windows using external SATA box. I get an `ERROR 2100 HDD0` initialization error.

Motherboard controller seems to be OK because other harddiscs are detected by the BIOS.

Maybe there is problem with data connector, controller or what will be worse memory is corrupted. I think it could be possible to get data from dead SSD somehow it doesn't have mechanical parts as classic HDD so if the problem is in SATA connector it should be done.

Beside OS I have there all work from school which is quite important set of data for me.

If there are some specialists who are doing this can you recommend some?

Comment: You did back up right?

Comment: No I don't have back up. If I have I don't ask how to recover data from dead SSD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any ideas out there as to how the data can be recovered from an SSD?](http://superuser.com/questions/253051/any-ideas-out-there-as-to-how-the-data-can-be-recovered-from-an-ssd)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The question was about how to get data from a dead SSD, not how to restore a backup.

Comment: While it's 4 years on...the point still stands. Data recovery is expensive. Backups are cheap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not specialist, yet it is one of the SSDs features that they are hard to recover.

Each manufacturer uses their own algorithms to distribute data over memory cells (as there is limited amount of write operations for each cell, it is crucial for the disk controller to use cells as equally as possible) - these algorithms are by nature very similar to cryptographic hash functions and thus it is hard to recover any data once the disk is dead.

Companies specializing in data-recovery should be able to help you as far as you have one of commonly used disks, yet it will not be cheap I'm afraid. Manufactures are not willing to expose their algorithms because they are closely connected with disk performance (more than hardware realization of the cells themselves), so the data-recovery companies usually sort-of reverse-engineer how controller distributes data in order to recover them.

We usually buy new disk rather than invest in data recovery - it is cheaper in the end, however, one must expect this to happen and make users not to store their data on the SSD (we usually provide them with SSD for OS and application and HDD and various network places (only these are backed-up) for their data)…

Comment: Yes I made a mistake that I didn't backed up my data.. Really funny is that that I had just OS there but as I thought SSD is safer than my 2nd HDD which is maybe failing cause it has some bad sectors, so I put there beside OS also data from school which are maybe only important data in my laptop for me.. And I didn't backed them up :(.. what is more funny I was thinking about backing up the data and what is sad I missed it and now my disk is dead :( But thanks for reply. Hope somebody maybe have some suggestion..

Comment: I think Matt's answer is the closest you are going to get. A dead SSD is about as impenetrable as devices get, because the data is not laid out in a linear pattern like on a HD.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I received mail from specialist in data recovery. He said that my OCZ SSD is using SandForce controller which is big problem because SandForce holds its know-how of data encrypting, and there is no firmware or service programs out from which can be made recovery software. Even if they solder out the memory blocks and solder them to some living device they wont be able to decode data in there. So it is possible to get data but software of controller provider is needed and also some skilled IT professional who can make recovery software from it. Sad news :(